# Transaction processing - Lookup millions of documents to validate transactions - Cost effective approach

Tags: python, postgresql, graphql, hashmap, couchbase

We recently made a shift from a relational to NoSQL (Couchbase). We are facing challenges scaling our backend to handle increasing number of users(reps). One of our product masters has over 50+ million documents and more than a million documents get modified on a day-to-day basis. There are few transactions that are processed daily which have product details in them, roughly 100,000 such transactions are processed with about 50 products in them. There is a need to check if these products are available in the product master which is a validation against 50+ million documents in Couchbase.

Our existing approach to lookup against 50+ million documents is not cost effective and increases the overall runtime of our service. We are exploring options to cache this locally or find an alternate way to perform this operation in a more efficient way.

Here is an overview of our existing data models.
Data structure 1 – Products authorized for a rep

| RepID | ProductId | Prod Start Dt | Prod End Dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1 | 2022-05-15 | 9999-12-25 |
| 1001 | 2 | 2022-05-15 | 9999-12-25 |
| 1001 | 3 | 2022-05-15 | 9999-12-25 |
| 1001 | 4 | 2022-05-15 | 9999-12-25 |
|  |  |  |  |
| 1002 | 1 | 2022-05-15 | 9999-12-25 |
| 1002 | 2 | 2022-05-15 | 9999-12-25 |
| 1002 | 5 | 2022-05-15 | 9999-12-25 |
| 1002 | 6 | 2022-05-15 | 9999-12-25 |
|  |  |  |  |
| 1003 | 1 | 2022-05-15 | 9999-12-25 |
| 1003 | 2 | 2022-05-15 | 9999-12-25 |
| 1003 | 8 | 2022-05-15 | 9999-12-25 |
| 1003 | 9 | 2022-05-15 | 9999-12-25 |

Similarly, 15,000 reps have an average of 3000-4000 documents totally to 50 million documents.

Transaction document model

| Order | RepID | ProductId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1001 | 1 |
| 1234 | 1001 | 2 |
| 1234 | 1001 | 3 |
| 1234 | 1001 | 4 |
| 1234 | 1001 | 5 |
|  |  |  |
| 100 | 1002 | 1 |
| 100 | 1002 | 2 |
| 100 | 1002 | 3 |
|  |  |  |
| 1111 | 1003 | 1 |
| 1111 | 1003 | 2 |
| 1111 | 1003 | 3 |
| 1111 | 1003 | 4 |

In the above example, rep 1001 isn’t authorized to sell product 5. Rep 1002 is not authorized to sell product 3 and rep 1003 is not authorized to sell products 3,4.
What is the most efficient way to validate these products in the order transaction comparing against millions of documents for Authorized products
One approach suggested was to use a HashMap with a list of reps and then another map for each of the reps’ authorized products. This would be in-memory cache and updated as and when new products are added to product master.

Second approach suggested was to use GraphQL or Postgres SQL as it might be effective for this kind of operation.
This is a simple problem, and the only challenge is to accomplish this in a cost-effective way without multiple DB calls or even eliminate all DB calls when transactions are processed by keeping this detail in memory. I would really appreciate if someone who has already tackled similar problems could share their experience on the technology stack, tools used.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if the Query Language that you used, had any affect on the cost-effectiveness of the operation.  I think that the classical answers to this type of question are "indexes" and "sharding"

Answer (score 1):

You might try thinking about using a pure KV solution leveraging Couchbase eventing. I think you will find that this real time solution essentially coding up a lambda or a trigger will be very performant across 10's of millions of documents. To this end I will give a concrete example below:

You seem to have two types of documents

First a sales rep authorization list here is essentially your data as JSON docs

```
  KEY  auth:1003 
  {
    "Products": [
      {
        "EndDt": "9999-12-25",
        "ProductId": 1,
        "StartDt": "2022-05-15"
      },
      {
        "EndDt": "9999-12-25",
        "ProductId": 2,
        "StartDt": "2022-05-15"
      },
      {
        "EndDt": "9999-12-25",
        "ProductId": 8,
        "StartDt": "2022-05-15"
      },
      {
        "EndDt": "9999-12-25",
        "ProductId": 9,
        "StartDt": "2022-05-15"
      }
    ],
    "id": 1003,
    "type": "auth"
  }


  KEY  auth:1002 
  {
    "Products": [
      {
        "EndDt": "9999-12-25",
        "ProductId": 1,
        "StartDt": "2022-05-15"
      },
      {
        "EndDt": "9999-12-25",
        "ProductId": 2,
        "StartDt": "2022-05-15"
      },
      {
        "EndDt": "9999-12-25",
        "ProductId": 5,
        "StartDt": "2022-05-15"
      },
      {
        "EndDt": "9999-12-25",
        "ProductId": 6,
        "StartDt": "2022-05-15"
      }
    ],
    "id": 1002,
    "type": "auth"
  }

  KEY  auth:1001 
  {
    "Products": [
      {
        "EndDt": "9999-12-25",
        "ProductId": 1,
        "StartDt": "2022-05-15"
      },
      {
        "EndDt": "9999-12-25",
        "ProductId": 2,
        "StartDt": "2022-05-15"
      },
      {
        "EndDt": "9999-12-25",
        "ProductId": 3,
        "StartDt": "2022-05-15"
      },
      {
        "EndDt": "9999-12-25",
        "ProductId": 4,
        "StartDt": "2022-05-15"
      }
    ],
    "id": 1001,
    "type": "auth"
  }
```

Second a bunch of orders coming in that you want to validate here is essentially your data as JSON docs (I took the liberty of adding one more to get a success)

```
  KEY: order:1234
  {
    "ProductIds": [
      1,2,3,4,5
    ],
    "RepID": 1001,
    "id": 1234,
    "type": "order"
  }

  KEY: order:1111
  {
    "ProductIds": [
      1,2,3,4
    ],
    "RepID": 1003,
    "id": 1111,
    "type": "order"
  }

  KEY: order:2222
  {
    "ProductIds": [
      8,9
    ],
    "RepID": 1003,
    "id": 2222,
    "type": "order"
  }

  KEY: order:100
  {
    "ProductIds": [
      1,2,3
    ],
    "RepID": 1002,
    "id": 100,
    "type": "order"
  }
```

Now here is an Eventing function (it will run in 6.X and 7.X mode although 7.X will be much faster if you take advantage of bucket backed caching)

```
// Need two buckets (if 7.0+ keyspaces of _default._default)
//     "eventing"
//     "data"
// Need one bucket binding 
//     alias = src_col bucket = data mode = r+w
// For performance set workers to 2X VCPUs for large data sets
// or for very fast mutation rates.

function OnUpdate(doc, meta) {
    // only process and validate orders (might add more filters here).
    if (doc.type !== "order") return;
    
    // level 1 is what you want, else to look at issue just raise the #
    var DEBUG = 1;
    // Use bucket backed caching to speed up loading of check document by 25X
    var VERSION_AT_702 = false;

    if (DEBUG > 1) log("checking order", meta.id);
    
    // load the rep's authorized products fromthe bucket binding.
    
    var auths;
    if (VERSION_AT_702 == false) {
        auths = src_col["auth:" + doc.RepID];
    } else {
        // use bucket backed caching.  Will only read KV at most once per 
        // second per each Eventing node. Costs  just 1/25th of a std. Bucket Op.
        var result = couchbase.get(src_col,{"id": "auth:" + doc.RepID}, {"cache": true});
        if (!result.success) {
            auths = null;
        } else {
            auths = result.doc;
        }
    }
    if (!auths) {
        if (DEBUG > 0) log("no auth record found for RepID", doc.RepID);
        return;
    }
    if (DEBUG > 4) log(auths);
    
    // since I save the lists this isn't an optimal check
    var is_authed = [];
    var is_not_authed = [];
    // now make sure the rep is authorized to sell all products
    for (var k = 0; k < doc.ProductIds.length; k++){
        var prod = doc.ProductIds[k];
        if (DEBUG > 1) log("checking product",prod);
        var okay = false;
        for (var j = 0; j < auths.Products.length; j++){
            var auth = auths.Products[j];
            if (DEBUG > 6) log("\t1.",auth);
            if (auth.ProductId == prod) {
                if (DEBUG > 8) log("\t\t2.",auth.ProductId," === ", prod, "GOOD");
                okay = true;
            } else {
                if (DEBUG > 8) log("\t\t2.",auth.ProductId," === ", prod, "BAD");
            }
        }
        if (okay === false) {
            is_not_authed.push(prod);
        } else {
            is_authed.push(prod);
        }
        if (DEBUG > 5) log("prod",prod,"authed",okay);
    }
    
    // =====================================================
    // we have an issue id is_not_authed.length > 0 
    //======================================================
    if (is_not_authed.length > 0) {
            if (DEBUG > 0) log("BAD illegal order", meta.id, "rep", doc.RepID, "can sell products", is_authed, "but can't sell products", is_not_authed);
    } else {
            if (DEBUG > 0) log("VALID legal order", meta.id, "rep", doc.RepID, "can sell products", is_authed);
    }
    // =====================================================
    // we could move the document or modify it but that's
    // you business logic.  Typically we might do something like:
    // 1. update the document with a new tag.
    //     doc.verify_status = (is_not_authed.length == 0)
    //     src_col[meta.id] = doc;
    // 2. at the top of the Function add another filter to 
    //    prevent redoing the same work.
    //     if (doc.verify_status) return;
    //======================================================    
}
```

Running the above Eventing function against the above data I get the following log messages.

```
2022-08-03T19:14:50.936+00:00 [INFO] "BAD illegal order" "order:1111" "rep" 1003 "can sell products" [1,2] "but can't sell products" [3,4] 

2022-08-03T19:14:50.848+00:00 [INFO] "BAD illegal order" "order:100" "rep" 1002 "can sell products" [1,2] "but can't sell products" [3] 

2022-08-03T19:14:50.812+00:00 [INFO] "VALID legal order" "order:2222" "rep" 1003 "can sell products" [8,9] 

2022-08-03T19:14:50.797+00:00 [INFO] "BAD illegal order" "order:1234" "rep" 1001 "can sell products" [1,2,3,4] "but can't sell products" [5]
```

Of course you want to do something other than log a message perhaps you want to move the document, add or update a property in the document, or do other actions after all your working with pure JavaScript with KV (or Data Service) access to your data in Couchbase.

Note in the above code I kept lists of what "can" and "cannot" be sold, but if you don't need that you can optimize the loop via breaks (JavaScript v8 is fast) but I do see that at your scale efficiency is key.

Maybe break out the Products into three arrays then you could do the following:

```
KEY  auth:1001 
{
  "id": 1001,
   "type": "auth",
  "Product": [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
  "StartDt": [ "2022-05-15", "2022-05-15", "2022-05-15", "2022-05-15" ],
  "StartDt": [ "9999-12-25", "9999-05-15", "9999-12-25", "9999-12-25" ]
}
```

The eliminate the for loops:

```
const includesAll = (arr, values) => values.every(v => arr.includes(v));
log(meta.id,includesAll(auths.Product, doc.ProductIds));
```

If the intersection "work" is too lengthy look into things like [FastBitSet.js](https://github.com/lemire/FastBitSet.js/blob/master/FastBitSet.js) to lower the analysis time.

The easiest way to increase the performance is to enable the bucket backed cache (requires version 7.0.2 or greater), however if you don't have reuse this won't help.  BTW emitting log messages will also slow things down too so avoid that.

IMHO you should be able to process 100K docs/second on a small cluster and up to 1M docs/sec on a large tuned cluster.

If you are not familiar with the Eventing Service you should run a few ["step by step" examples](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/eventing/eventing-examples.html) first to get a basic understanding.

If for some reason you need more performance (I don't think you will) there are a few advanced Eventing tricks that I can share to speed things up even no - just DM me and we'll schedule some time to talk.

Comment: FYI, I loaded 20M "orders" (average of 50 products random selection) and 15K reps (authorized to sell an average of 3.5K products random selection) across 1M products.as per your specs 1) basic straightforward implementation I processed 5K orders/sec., and 2)  with a bit of "magic/tricks" in the Eventing Service achieved 216K orders/sec. on a one (1) node Couchbase server.

Comment: Thanks for your Inputs Jon. Our Couchbase architect suggested a similar approach but we dropped it as it was decided not to use eventing in this bucket where these documents are present. I'll run your solution by him. Thanks again for your response.